# iOS API for making a panorama?

Tags: iphone, ios6, panoramas

Is there a way to easily programmatically create a panorama in the iOS?
I want to include a way to create a panorama in my iPhone app, leveraging iOS6s new panorama feature, so I don't have to implement it from scratch. If Apple does not provide and API, are there any good third party libraries to help make panoramas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use camera to capture image with timer and after stitches image using opencv

[openCV 2.4.3 iOS framework compiler trouble recognising some c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905471/opencv-2-4-3-ios-framework-compiler-trouble-recognising-some-c-headers)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this OpenCV Image stitching project:

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch