# objective-c wrapper invoking c++ static member functions

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make an objective-c++ wrapper (.mm) between a pure c++ class (.cpp) and pure objective-c object (.m). A good working example can be [found on github](https://github.com/boralben/ObjectiveCPPWrapperEx.git). I can build and run this without a problem.

However I need to access static member functions  in the c++ class. I have modified the github example by removing all existing functions and introducing a static member function:

```
//  ==================
//  DummyModel.h
//  ==================

class DummyModel
{
    public:
        static int test ();

};

//  ==================
//  DummyModel.cpp
//  ==================

#include "DummyModel.h"


static int test ()
{
    int x = 1;
    return x;
}


//  ==================
//  DummyModelWrapper.h
//  ==================

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DummyModelWrapper : NSObject

- (int) test;

@end

//  ==================
//  DummyModelWrapper.mm
//  ==================

#import "DummyModelWrapper.h"
#import "DummyModel.h"

@implementation DummyModelWrapper

- (int) test
{
    int result;
    result = DummyModel::test();
    return result;
}

@end
```

This yields the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "DummyModel::test()", referenced from:
      -[DummyModelWrapper test] in DummyModelWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It is this reference to test in DummyModelWrapper.mm that is invoking the error:

```
   result = DummyModel::test();
```

The test project is adapted from the github project, which compiles and runs fine in it's unedited form (it instantiates `DummyModel` and invokes member functions on the instance). The error occurs as soon as I attempt to add a static member and access it from the wrapper object.

I have read everything i can find on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but can only find examples involving non-static member functions.

*references*
http://www.philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++
http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-cppfinal-edition-759
http://www.boralapps.com/an-objective-c-project-that-uses-c/294/

*environment*
xcode 4.5.2/osx8.2 (targeting ios5+)

Comment: If you're invoking C++ code in that ".m" file, shouldn't it be a ".mm" file extension instead? Or perhaps the comment in the source file is inaccurate? Regardless, see [benjorbin's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104510/objective-c-wrapper-invoking-c-static-member-functions/14104585#14104585) answer below.

Comment: yes, sorry that was a bad typo, fixed in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside DummyModel.cpp, replace

```
static int test ()
{
    ...
}
```

By

```
int DummyModel::test ()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks that does fix it, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't the definition and declaration signatures should match?  Can you point me to any clear online references?

Comment: This is fundamental class/namespace method definition logic - your declaration must contain the class specifier, otherwise it's not a method of the class, but a simple function (and in this case a static function) - this is due to C++ being based on it's C roots

Comment: @Petesh, as you have noticed my c++ knowledge is very rudimentary. `Static` seems to have many uses. To quote Bruce Eckel's __Thinking in C++__ "The static keyword was overloaded in C before people knew what the term “overload” meant, and C++ has added yet another meaning." (he later describes it as 'confusing'). I am doing lots of reading now. I asked this question to help me with [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958321/iosretrieve-rectangle-shaped-image-from-the-background-image) on c++ and obj-c, and it taught me how little I know. I managed to get it working though.