# OpenCV Detect Circles in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I am trying to detect circles in an image (that contains an empty plate).

I have tried using HoughCircles and minEnclosingCircle but no luck using the code in my iOS app.

I code I am trying to port to iOS is located at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html#hough-circle

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how I convert this code to Objective C..

Comment: In the current form, your question is not answerable at all. You need to be more specific. What is the code that you have tried? Where are you struggling?

Comment: comment moved to answer...

Comment: Did you solved this ?