# Can Opencv developed in c/cpp - Run in IOS?

Tags: ios, macos, ios5, image-processing, opencv

I am developing an image processing application in Centos with OpenCV using C/C++ coding. My intension is to have a single development platform for Linux and IOS (IPAD). 
So if I start the development in a Linux environment with OpenCV installed ( in C/CPP ),Can I use the same code in IOS without going for Objective-C? I don't want to put dual effort for IOS and Linux, so how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html) it's possible.  Compiling and running C/C++ on iOS is no problem, but you'll need some Objective-C for the UI.  When you pay some attention to the layering/abstraction of your modules, you should be able to share most/all core code between the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

See my detailed answer to this question:
[iOS:Retrieve rectangle shaped image from the background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958321/iosretrieve-rectangle-shaped-image-from-the-background-image/14123682#comment19597798_14123682)

Basically you can keep most of your CPP code portable between platforms if you keep your user interface code separate. On iOS all of the UI should be pure objective-C, while your openCV image processing can be pure C++ (which would be exactly the same on linux). On iOS you would make a thin ObjC++ wrapper class that mediates between Objective-C side and the C++ side. All it really does is translate image formats between them and send data in and out of C++ for processing.

I have a couple of simple examples on github you might want to take a look at: [OpenCVSquares](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares) and [OpenCVStitch](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch). These are based on C++ samples distributed with openCV - you should compare the C++ in those projects with the original samples to see how much altering was required (hint: not much).