# OpenCv 2.4.9 on iOS background_segm.hpp #include <list> not found

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I'm trying to bridge OpenCV c++ to my Swift application.

And I'm getting this error:

```
Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/MDAcne-Bridging-Header.h:14:9: note: in file included from /Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/MDAcne-Bridging-Header.h:14:
#import "cvVideoWrapper.h"
        ^
/Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/cvVideoWrapper.h:13:9: note: in file included from /Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/cvVideoWrapper.h:13:
#import "algo.hpp"
        ^
/Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/algo.hpp:11:10: note: in file included from /Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/algo.hpp:11:
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
         ^
/Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/Pods/OpenCV/opencv2.framework/Headers/video/background_segm.hpp:47:10: error: 'list' file not found
#include <list>
         ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/MDAcne-Bridging-Header.h'
```

cvVideoWrapper.h and cvVideoWrapper.mm connect between the bridging header to algo.hpp which is the c++ file.
algo.hpp includes those libraries:

```
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
```

which contains `#include <list>` which is a C file that is causing the problem as I understand.

I saw in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20902063/527106) that this can be fixed by changing the .m files to .mm files. I've done this and I still get this error. In addition seems that in my case it's happening in the cvVideoWrapper.h  file.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

`#include <list>`

is a C++ header, so you need to build with the obj-c++ compiler. Depending on your build environment, using the .mm suffix is often sufficient to invoke the obj-c++ compiler.

How are you building this?  And what file is including

```
/Users/admin/Desktop/MDAcne/MDAcne/MDAcne-Bridging-Header.h
```

That file also needs a .mm suffix...

Edit: as discussed below, the user was trying to include obj-c++ directly from swift.  This will not work:

[Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files)

Use an obj-c++ wrapper and don't include the c++ headers from swift; nothing on the direct include chain can reference c++.  So, move the:

```
#include <list>
```

to the cvVideoWrapper.mm file.  You may have to re-architect things a bit.

Comment: I'm building with libstdc++ . And MDAcne-Bridging-Header.h imports  "cvVideoWrapper.h"

Comment: Yes, but what imports MDAcne-Bridging-Header.h?

Comment: If for example you have a MDAcne-Bridging-Header.m, that file also needs the .mm suffix.

Comment: The bridging header connects to the Objective C with the Swift code. I don't have MDAcne-Bridging-Header.m / MDAcne-Bridging-Header.mm file, only the header.

Comment: You can't include obj-c++ directly from swift.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the PrefixHeader file. After removing this import my problem is solved.

[image]